# Retaining data in Apache Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have just started reading about Apache kafka few days back so I am sort of newbie in this technology. I have some doubts/queries and need to get clarification. Such as:

1. As per configuration:  `log.retention.hours` we can set duration in hours here. **Can data retention time be extended for 2 years ?**
2. As per this [link](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#persistence) it says:

> The Kafka cluster retains all published messages—whether or not they have been consumed—for a configurable period of time. For example if the log retention is set to two days, then for the two days after a message is published it is available for consumption, after which it will be discarded to free up space. Kafka's performance is effectively constant with respect to data size so retaining lots of data is not a problem.

As it already says **Perfomance is effectively constant with respect to data size**. So does that mean we can store the data as much as possible ? does it require some additional configuration or monitor ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Sure. log.retention.hours is an integer. 2 years is just 17520 hours. Well below the maximal value for an integer.

2) You can store as much data as will fit in the disks you have. Just note that while Kafka's performance does not degrade if you store more data, a consumer that will try to get massive amounts of data from the disk will absolutely impact performance. For best performance make sure consumer read relatively recent data while its still retained in memory.

Answer (score 1):

`log.retention.hours` can hold way higher value then 100 years, so do not worry about it. As for your second question, it mean that time to retrieve your messages in `O(1)`.

So no matter how much data will be there the time for retrieval will not change.